# How to change text color in Markdown in Emacs for italics and quotes?

Tags: emacs, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Basically, when I have a Markdown file opened in Emacs, I want the italics and quotes to be a different color. If I write:

> "Hello, world!"

I want the quotation marks and the text between them to be a different color than the rest of the text in the file.

Same goes for italics.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

For italics it's easy, just customize `markdown-italic-face`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'markdown-italic-face nil :foreground "magenta") ;; or "#ff00ff"
```

For quotes, you'd need to add a font-lock rule to match quoted strings and apply a different face.  It might be non-trivial.